# Scale vertically stacked buttons with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have 4 buttons with UILabels under them. It looks good on the iPhone 6, but I'm having trouble getting the buttons to stay in the same configuration with Auto Layout. I've tried constraining the Aspect Ratio and the distances to the edges, but the aspect ratio still gets distorted. I deleted all the constraints for now.

[image: Vertical buttons]

What approach should I take?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the picture you posted? If so, what? If not, then please post a picture that shows what you don't like, and explain what you don't like about it.

Comment: You need to post code or some detail on what you tried and what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use equal height constrains (red = orange, orange = blue, blue = purple) in conjunction with vertical spacing zero (same way between red and orange)

Pin the labels to the bottom (the white views in my example).

The leading and trailing of the buttons are also pinned to the borders of the superview to define the horizontal size.
[image]

Comment: can you explain this a bit more? Do I select all of the views and add the equal height constraint all at once?

Comment: selected the red and orange view (in my example), make the height equal, repeat the same for the orange and blue, blue and purple

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to get your requirement done.

Give Each Button to label "**Vertical Spacing**" & "**Center-Y**".

The first button to it's superView "**Top Space to Top Layout Guide**".

The last button to it's superView "**Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide**".

set Each button to it's superView "**Center Vertically in container**".

Fix Buttons-Labels; heights & widths.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this , you have to add constraints for - leading space, trailing space, top space and aspect ratio for each element.

**Constraint for Button:**

[image: Constraint for Button]

**Constraint for Label:**

[image: Constraint for Label]

Comment: Okay, this almost works, but the buttons get really, really small of the iPhone 5 and 4.

Comment: What is the size (width, height) of button and label?